# AOSP: Write a file on /data directory

Tags: android, android-permissions, selinux

I want to write a file on "/data" directory. I have rooted my device and setenforce 0. However, I am getting:

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data/MyDoople.txt
>   (Permission denied)

Here is my code (it works for sdcard):

```
String filename= "MyDoople.txt";
try
{
    File f = new File("data/"+File.separator+filename);

    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(f);
    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
            fOut);
    myOutWriter.append("Mytest");
    myOutWriter.close();
    fOut.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Do I have to add any policy to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Because the permission of the data directory is rwxrwx--x, user system, group system, and the running user of your app is a common user, not a system user, so the app unable to read and write the /data directory directly.

Two ways can be referred to:

1: If you have a platform certificate, declare android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in AndroidManifest.xml, and use the platform certificate to re-sign the app. In this way, the user running your app is the system user, who has read and write permissions to the /data partition.

2: obtain the root permission in the app, and then execute the relevant command, refer to:

```
    public static boolean RootCommand(String command) {
    Process process = null;
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(command + "\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("*** DEBUG ***", "ROOT REE" + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (os != null) {
                os.close();
            }
            process.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    Log.d("*** DEBUG ***", "Root SUC ");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: mmm...nice explanation...but let s say I cant be rooted (I rooted to see if it was possible). The app is a postloaded app (so not system) but I have the certificate of the app. Is there something I can add so that only this app can write on /fwupdate ?